# Android - how can i from window1 go to window2 then go to window3 from window3 jump back to window1?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I have 3 window (activity). window1 buttons with old pictures, window2 options to change the old pictures of window1, window3 preview of the pictures.

when selection is made in window3 i want to skip quite window2 + window3 and jump back to window1. How can we do that?

[image]

Window1:

```
Intent MyRotationsAddPicture2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyRotationsAddPicture.class);
MyRotationsAddPicture2.putExtra("Title", "r2.jpg");
startActivityForResult(MyRotationsAddPicture2,0);
```

Window2 / Window3 ?

```
String whichImage =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title"); 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (resultCode == 0) {
      finish();
      startActivity(getIntent());

    }
}

setResult(0);
this.finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like you want is you don't want to use `startActivityForResult()` here...just use `startActivity()`.

In `Activity3` use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, Activity1.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

use this if you don't want to remove `Activity2` from the stack.

If you DO want to remove `Activity2` from the stack simply use the flags

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

or call `finish()` in `Activity2` when moving to `Activity3`

You can find all of the `Intent Flags` [Here in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Thank you. Excellent. One last question. 1) Activity1.class is perfectly coming back on front 2) but is it possible to reload Activity1.class, because Activity3 has created a new picture which need to be refreshed while i do that `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);` is there still a way?

Comment: You can override `onResume()` and update whatever `view` you need to there. That way you don't have to redraw the whole screen

Comment: Great. Also found i can do it with `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  ` Thank you so much. Working perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to mention that but there's really no need to if you only want to update one `View`. It may not make much of a difference depending on what you have. You're welcome

Comment: YES - you are 100% correct. Thank you so much its working great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT, in Window1 keeps your same code.
In Window2, start Window3

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Window3.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

In Window3 just set the result but do not call `System.exit(0)`. You will get the result in Window1 `onActivityResult`.